# which library should i use in order to compile with boost algorithm

Tags: c++, boost

I am using a self compiled boost library, have to add libraries for compiling, but I can't tell which boost library should I add in order to use Boost::Algorithm, There is not a clear named library file for it like 'libboost_regex' for "regex" and 'libboost_thread' for "thread".

Comment: `boost::algorithm` is header-only, there is no compiled library file.

Answer (score 1):

Only a small number of boost libraries must be built and linked against your application. The list is on their [Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries) page. Here it is:

```
Boost.Chrono
Boost.Context
Boost.Filesystem
Boost.GraphParallel
Boost.IOStreams
Boost.Locale
Boost.MPI
Boost.ProgramOptions
Boost.Python (see the Boost.Python build documentation before building and installing it)
Boost.Regex
Boost.Serialization
Boost.Signals
Boost.System
Boost.Thread
Boost.Timer
Boost.Wave
```

As you can see, `Boost.Algorithm` is not on there. In order to use it, you need only include the header file(s).